# What triggers the creation of beans in Spring Batch 5 when using @EnableBatchProcessing?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I am using the `@EnableBatchProcessing` annotation in my Spring Batch 5 application, but the Spring Batch beans are not being activated.

The `BatchConfigurationSelector` and `BatchConfigurer` classes have been removed in Spring Batch 5, and the `BatchAutoConfiguration` is not activated due to the `@ConditionalOnMissingBean(value = DefaultBatchConfiguration.class, annotation = EnableBatchProcessing.class)` condition.

I am not sure if this is a bug in Spring Batch 5 or if I have misconfigured something.

If I have misconfigured something, I would like to know how I can activate the Spring Batch beans using the `@EnableBatchProcessing` annotation.

Thanks.

What I tried: I am using `@EnableBatchProcessing` in my Spring Batch 5 project, but the Spring Batch beans are not being activated.

What I expected: I expected that the `@EnableBatchProcessing` annotation would activate the Spring Batch beans and that my project would be properly configured for batch processing.

What actually happened: The Spring Batch beans are not being activated, and I am not sure if this is a bug in Spring Batch 5 or if I have misconfigured something. I would like to know the process of how the beans are activated when using the `@EnableBatchProcessing` annotation in Spring Batch 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Spring Boot 3, there is no need for `@EnableBatchProcessing`. If you add it, the auto-configuration of Spring Batch (meta-data tables creation, launching of jobs at startup, etc) will back off.

This is mentioned in the [migration guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0-Migration-Guide#spring-batch-changes) of Spring Boot 3.